# what could be the issue with my ssh-copy-id command?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, putty

I generated the key for passwordless ssh on my centos machine 1(lab 2),

```
[root@cdl-lab-2 centos]# ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
fc:55:88:d5:f6:db:2b:b2:46:97:a0:e3:9e:b9:fb:73 root@cdl-lab-2
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|            ..   |
|           o .o  |
|          . .... |
|       .   . .  .|
|        S . o . o|
|         + o o ..|
|        . + .   .|
|         .o+ E . |
|        .*=o= .  |
+-----------------+
```

then copied it to the authorized_keys.

```
cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now i can ssh to my machine(lab2) without password. But i cannot copy the key file to machine 2. So i can ssh to it without password. For now i cannot even get in with passport from machine 1 with password. The following error is thrown

```
[root@cdl-lab-2 ~]# sudo ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub centos@lab3
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Note: i have to connect with the machine using putty(user,password and also a putty private key file)

I believe i have to place this file in the system somewhere. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 2):

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

This means that the machine you are trying to connect does not accept password authentication and therefore you can't copy the key there using a password.

> I believe i have to place this file in the system somewhere. Can anyone help.

Yes. The place is `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the remote side is not asking for a password, instead requiring a key to connect.  Look in your /etc/ssh/sshd.config file on lab3 and see if you have a line which says

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

If so, change the `no` to `yes` and restart the sshd service.  That should then allow passwords to be used.